# How to export color of polygon from Autocad into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, autocad

I use Qgis 2.14. I have some problem with export .dgn to shp from Autocad. Qgis appropriates random colors to my polygons after export. Somebody knows how i can export original color of my Autocad dgn?

Comment: As far as I am aware QGIS has no tool to import styles and colors from DXFs / DGNs - and I deal with this issue pretty often. I use other commercial software to import DXFs into GIS format which allows me to keep informations about layers, colors, elevetion etc. At this moment QGIS can't do any of that. Only export to DXF in new versions of QGIS is supported pretty well. But not the other way around.

Comment: What program are you using to keep information?

Comment: For the simple import including colors, texts and layer names I use Mapinfo Discover. It is far from perfect but sufficient in most of the cases. If you need something professional, FME is the way to go, free trial... https://www.safe.com/convert/dwg/arcgis-shp/

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the style Layer (.qml or sld).
2. Export .dgn to shp.
3. Load your shp.
4. Load style(.qml or .sld) for this shape.

[image]