# Creating a palette for categorized data displays

Tags: qgis, data, style, color, display

I regularly categorize data as follows:

Prehistoric = blue
Roman = red
Anglo-saxon = green
Medieval = yellow
Post-medieval = brown
Modern = grey
Undated = white

Is there any way to save this palette and associate it with the period names so that it can be loaded? I never change the period names, although sometimes there is no data for certain periods.

Its time consuming to have to change the colours for each period, so I am seeking any advice on how to save the colour scheme? I have tried style files (which I already use on layers with a single display requirement0 but these don't seem to be the right things.

Comment: You can save categorized style (as any other style) as qml file (Save as default for layer or save as...) in QGIS which you can after load. Or also simply copy and paste within QGIS project. Is that what you are after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the same case.

[How to export color of polygon from Autocad into QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190971/how-to-export-color-of-polygon-from-autocad-into-qgis/192437#192437)

You only need save your style and after load it with Qgis interface or programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

There's a shortcut which may help here:

1. From the symbol library (Settings -> Style Manager) create a bunch of symbols with names which exactly match your categories (eg Prehistoric, Roman, etc)
2. Setup a categorized renderer for your layer, select the corresponding field and classify.
3. Click the "Advanced" button and select "match to saved symbols". The categories will be automatically matched to the symbols in your library with the same name, ie Prehistoric, Roman, etc!